# Add a cell renderer using Glade

Tags: gtk, glade

I'm using Glade to build a GTK user interface for my Rust program.

The issue is that items that are added to the ListStore are not showing up. I have horizontal lines set up that show up, but the text of the items is not showing up. I Googled and I suspect it's because of the cell renderers. I have tried to add a cell renderer in Glade, however I didn't see anywhere where could I do that. I right click on the treeview, click Edit, right click on the row/column but nothing about cell renderers is displayed.

How can I add a cell renderer using Glade?

```
$ glade --version
glade 3.22.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

It's very hard to find. I search lots of tutorial but many of them are very old, so the interface was quite different.

1. Right click GtkTreeView and choose "Edit"
2. On top left sub area, click blue "+" sign to add a new column.
3. right click newly created column, choose add child text
4. You will see Cell Render area showing up to the right.
5. In "Properties and Attributes", set "Text" properties to the column you wish to present.

Comment: Damn, that took some finding.  Have my upvote.